# Don't show default Outlook Data File (.pst) on startup

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, imap

You can't remove the default Outlook data file (see [here](https://superuser.com/questions/261109/remove-outlook-data-file) or [here](https://support.office.com/article/49ccb5d3-884c-43ea-b72b-a295070df214?rs=en-us)). But I don't want that the inbox of the empty data file (only used for storing calendar events, because IMAP can't handle this) is opened as default.

I tried to add my inbox folder as favorite and put it on top. I also removed the other favorites, but every time I open Outlook 2010 the inbox folder of the default data file is opened. Also in the account settings I set my IMAP account as default. Nothing helps.

How can I set my IMAP account to open as default on startup in Outlook 2010?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Outlook, chose File/Options, and then the item 'Advanced'. On that screen, you can chose with what folder Outlook should start:
[image]